# SQL for precision and recall?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table containing two versions of results for some predictors, one by human labeling and the other by machine predicting, and I want to calculate some metrics.

```
CREATE TABLE log_table (
  `id` VARCHAR(5),
  `version` VARCHAR(15),
  `result` FlOAT
);

INSERT INTO log_table
  (`id`, `version`, `result`)
VALUES
  ('001', '2020-12-10', 0.8),
  ('002', '2020-12-10', 0.1),
  ('003', '2020-12-10', 0.2),
  ('004', '2020-12-10', 0.9),
  ('001', 'ground_truth', 1),
  ('002', 'ground_truth', 0),
  ('003', 'ground_truth', 1),
  ('004', 'ground_truth', 0),
  ('005', 'ground_truth', 1);
```

Here I tried to work out the [recall and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall).

```
SELECT true_positive / ( true_positive + false_negative )  AS recall,
       true_positive / ( true_positive + false_positive ) AS _precision
FROM   (SELECT (SELECT Count(*) AS true_positive
                FROM   (SELECT id,
                               IF(result > 0.5, 1, 0) AS predict_result
                        FROM   log_table
                        WHERE  version = "2020-12-10") AS t_left
                       JOIN (SELECT id,
                                    result
                             FROM   log_table
                             WHERE  version = "ground_truth"
                                    AND result = 1) AS t_right
                         ON t_left.id = t_right.id
                            AND t_left.predict_result = t_right.result)  AS
                      true_positive,
               (SELECT Count(*) AS false_negative
                FROM   (SELECT id,
                               IF(result > 0.5, 1, 0) AS predict_result
                        FROM   log_table
                        WHERE  version = "2020-12-10") AS t_left
                       JOIN (SELECT id,
                                    result
                             FROM   log_table
                             WHERE  version = "ground_truth"
                                    AND result = 1) AS t_right
                         ON t_left.id = t_right.id
                            AND t_left.predict_result != t_right.result) AS
                      false_negative,
               (SELECT Count(*) AS false_positive
                FROM   (SELECT id,
                               IF(result > 0.5, 1, 0) AS predict_result
                        FROM   log_table
                        WHERE  version = "2020-12-10") AS t_left
                       JOIN (SELECT id,
                                    result
                             FROM   log_table
                             WHERE  version = "ground_truth"
                                    AND result = 0) AS t_right
                         ON t_left.id = t_right.id
                            AND t_left.predict_result != t_right.result) AS
                      false_positive,
               (SELECT Count(*) AS true_negative
                FROM   (SELECT id,
                               IF(result > 0.5, 1, 0) AS predict_result
                        FROM   log_table
                        WHERE  version = "2020-12-10") AS t_left
                       JOIN (SELECT id,
                                    result
                             FROM   log_table
                             WHERE  version = "ground_truth"
                                    AND result = 0) AS t_right
                         ON t_left.id = t_right.id
                            AND t_left.predict_result = t_right.result)  AS
                      true_negative) AS metrics;
```

The code above seems not only complicated but also repetitive, then I wonder if it would be optimized and simplified? [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/brCyWqTTGwAjTgr7szWTu2/1) is its fiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally you just need to rethink how your aggregation is done. The RDBMS you use - MySQL - [is broken and does not support](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) standard [aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES).

Applying some `filter`s and replacing your conditional with a `round` makes this problem trivial if you're able to use PostgreSQL instead:

```
select cast(true_pos as real) / (true_pos + false_neg) as recall,
       cast(true_pos as real) / (true_pos + false_pos) as precision
from (
  select
      count(*) filter(where t_act.result=0 and t_exp.result=1) as false_neg,
   -- count(*) filter(where t_act.result=0 and t_exp.result=0) as true_neg,
      count(*) filter(where t_act.result=1 and t_exp.result=0) as false_pos,
      count(*) filter(where t_act.result=1 and t_exp.result=1) as true_pos
  from (
    select id, round(result) as result
    from log_table
    where version = '2020-12-10'
  ) as t_act
  join log_table as t_exp
    on t_act.id = t_exp.id and t_exp.version = 'ground_truth'
) as metrics;
```

[sqlfiddle.com also supports this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e3bb4/8).

However, since you're stuck with MySQL you could use the `case` workaround proposed in that modern-sql site:

```
select true_pos / (true_pos + false_neg) as recall,
       true_pos / (true_pos + false_pos) as 'precision'
from (
  select
      count(case when t_act.result=0 and t_exp.result=1 then 1 end) as false_neg,
      count(case when t_act.result=1 and t_exp.result=0 then 1 end) as false_pos,
      count(case when t_act.result=1 and t_exp.result=1 then 1 end) as true_pos
  from (
    select id, round(result) as result
    from log_table
    where version = '2020-12-10'
  ) as t_act
  join log_table as t_exp
    on t_act.id = t_exp.id and t_exp.version = 'ground_truth'
) as metrics;
```

Comment: The code is neat, but it seems not to work in MySQL.

Comment: @Lnz right; which is why I mentioned that explicitly along with a workaround. Why are you using MySQL?

Comment: We can only use MySQL in our company. :(

Comment: Facetiously: sounds like you need a new company. But anyway, the link above describes a workaround for MySQL.

Comment: @Lnz done; and confirmed in db-fiddle.com